# Manipulate createdAt field with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

For testing purposes I would like to control the `createdAt` field in my MongoDb object. Unfortunately I'm afraid that this isn't possible with standard [timestamp](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) implementation. Here's the gist of the code that I'm using to create some objects and then setting their created timestamp:

```
const docArray = [];
const times = [15, 32, 1233, 122].map(seconds => moment().add(seconds, 'seconds'));

for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i += 1) {
  // Create an object
  docArray.push(await createObj(`${i}`));

  const doc2update = await MyModel.findById(docArray[i]._id);
  // Save the original created date
  const org = doc2update.createdAt;

  // Do the update
  doc2update.createdAt = times[i];
  doc2update.save(); // tried doc2update.update() without change

  // Retrieve the updated object
  docArray[i] = await TaskModel.findById(docArray[i]._id);

  // Check if change preserved
  console.log(docArray[i].createdAt - org,
              'vs expected',
              doc2update.createdAt - org);
}
```

The output is rather disappointing

```
0 'vs expected' 14841
0 'vs expected' 31809
0 'vs expected' 1232787
0 'vs expected' 121762
```

I guess that manipulating created in this way is not recommended for regular use but it would convenient when testing. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @nadavvadan: I want to calculate the median time between created objects (actually subdocuments) but then I would like to control the createdAt timestamp. I could ofcourse just add the objects with a delay but it would be (1) adding unnecessary test time (2) lack the same precision as I still wouldn't control the precise time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [manipulate timestamp in mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/a7df1594d7e973e3545f02b5615cc5f96f61e218/lib/schema.js#L823), just like any other value in your document.

Your test fails, because `.save()` is async function and you should wait for it to finish as well.

```
await doc2update.save();
```

Comment: Thanks! The frustration of coding... Tested to set the updatedAt but as expected, by the code snippet you link to, it gets overwritten with a new timestamp.